# Trouble with some openweathermap API example code

Tags: javascript, jquery, openweathermap

I am trying to run the following code:

```
var mainWeather = {
  init: function() {
    $("#submitWeather").click(function() {
      return mainWeather.getWeather();
    });
  },

  getWeather: function() {
    $.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + $("#cityInput").val() + "," + $("#countryInput").val() + "&APPID=myweatherkey_removed", function(data) {
      var json = {
        json: JSON.stringify(data),
        delay: 1
      };
      echo(json);
    });
  },

  // Prints result from the weatherapi, receiving as param an object
  createWeatherWidg: function(data) {
    return "<div class='pressure'> <p>Temperature: " + (data.main.temp - 273.15).toFixed(2) + " C</p></div>" +
      "<div class='description'> <p>Title: " + data.weather[0].main + "</p></div>" +
      "<div class='description'> <p>Description: " + data.weather[0].description + "</p></div>" +
      "<div class='wind'> <p>Wind Speed: " + data.wind.speed + "</p></div>" +
      "<div class='humidity'> <p>Humidity: " + data.main.humidity + "%</p></div>" +
      "<div class='pressure'> <p>Pressure: " + data.main.pressure + " hpa</p></div>";
  }
  };

  var echo = function(dataPass) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/echo/json/",
    data: dataPass,
    cache: false,
    success: function(json) {
      var wrapper = $("#weatherWrapper");
      wrapper.empty();
      wrapper.append("<div class='city'> <p>Place: " + json.name + ", " + json.sys.country + "</p></div>");
      wrapper.append(mainWeather.createWeatherWidg(json));
    }
  });
};

mainWeather.init();
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Open Weather API</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="userArea" class="container">
            <div id="stateWrapper">
                <input type="text" id="cityInput" placeholder="Enter a State" />
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="countryWrapper">
                <input type="text" id="countryInput" placeholder="Enter a Country" />
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div id="buttonArea">
                <input type="submit" id="submitWeather" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                <br/>
            </div>
            <!- USED TO SHOW RESULT -->
            <div id="weatherWrapper">
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.1.slim.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mainWeather.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it just won't do anything when I hit submit.

The Chrome debugger is saying first that $.get is not a function in line 9, so after searching, I changed it to jquery.get. Now it says that is not a function. I have no idea what I'm doing. Can anybody figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The slim build of jQuery excludes Ajax. You can read more [here](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/06/09/jquery-3-0-final-released/). 
Just change it out with the normal build and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you for responding. However, running it using normal jquery now produces this error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/echo/json/. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: You are using the file protocol instead of  http protocol. Use a local server and it will work. Search and install XAMPP or WampServer. If you read the Error: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http ...

Comment: The original code does a call to `url: "/echo/json/",` which is a local url.

Comment: I copied that code from his jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JeriesHG/5h2k68b7/14/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=5h2k68b7

Comment: Oh, ajax calls have to be simulated on jsfiddle. I honestly can't figure out why he did that ajax call to send json.